# How to get the button from cell in UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a custom cell in iOS.On the custom cells,i have added 5 buttons.On click of button i am making a network request & when request is done i want to change the background image of the button.For making button clicked i have added IBOutlet of each button & i have added the tag of each button as indexpath.row.

```
cell.btn_like.tag=indexPath.row;
```

After that i have listener method as:

```
- (IBAction)tapped_liked:(id)sender
{
    if([self isNetworkConnected])
    {
        [self makeLikePost:(int)[sender tag]];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"No Internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    NSLog(@"tapped liked %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
}
```

on `makeLikePost` method i am doing following.

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellIndex inSection:1];

    HomeCell *cell = [self.table_view

                      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeCell"

                      forIndexPath:indexPath];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                            user_post.id, @"post_id", nil];

    NSLog(@"post id is %@",user_post.id);

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:api_key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

     {

         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


         [cell.btn_like setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sel_like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)

     {
     }];
```

Comment: but i am not able to get the button.

Comment: have you tried on dispatching on main queue block?

Comment: How can i get the button for each cell which i pressed i want to change the background image of the button.

Comment: you should get cell with cellForRowAtIndexPath not with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

First get the button from cell through tag .

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellIndex inSection:1];

HomeCell *cell = [self.table_view

                  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeCell"

                  forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:IndexPath.row];
```

// In your completion block ..

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sel_like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

hope it will work for you .

Answer (score 0):

`Try with this change`

```
HomeCell *cell = [self.table_view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

With

```
HomeCell *cell = [self.table_view cellForRowAtIndexpath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Hi i have checked your codeIt does not work fine.I have made an array in which i saved the index path of each cell.I am geting the index path by passing the row index & get the indexpath

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)likeButtonClicked:(id)sender

{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   CGPoint buttonPosition =[sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableviewname];
   NSIndexPath*indexPath =[self.tableviewname indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition]; 
  customCellName *cell = (customCellName*)[toView:tableviewname cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  //CGPoint = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableviewname];

   // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [toView:tableviewname indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootPoint];

    //and from here you can access of any view inside cell using this cell object

   //some thing like cell.your button name
}
```

Hope this will help to you :)

Comment: Still i am not able to get the button on the particular cell.Please tell me how can i get the button.

Comment: For what you want button, to change your tapped button image on particular cell ?

Comment: Yes for that reason i want

Comment: As i have shared the code.I am able to tap & call a function on the button but still i am not able to change the color of button when my network operation is done.

Comment: just checking.please stay

Comment: How to pass button position ?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/blocks-and-table-view-cells-on-ios--mobile-22982 plz check this link carefully.

Comment: Please tell me how can i get the button position here?

Comment: I am not able to understand your concept here.

Comment: We created object named button position which gives cgpoint value and using that point we can get indexpath of that cell but this code is same as previous.plz check the given link.above code is working at my side any ways check the link and try

Comment: i can get the cell using cellforrowindexatpath.then why i neeed cgpoint

Comment: is this the only solution that i need to impelment

Comment: **UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        
        // Find Point in Superview
        CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.table_view];
        
        // Infer Index Path
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table_view indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];
        
        // Fetch Item
        HomeCell *cell=(HomeCell *)[self.table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.btn_like setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sel_like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal
         ];**